# Issues with visited state for <a> tag in HTML and Google Analytics?

Tags: html, css, google-analytics, hyperlink, anchor

Every reload page, the href attribute will be different because of the change of _gl params value.So browser can't detect the visited state as I expect.

Here's a link example.
https://www.example.com?_gl=1*1grxygz*_ga*_T224E9THM0*MTY3OTMwMjQ5MC41OC4xLjE2NzkzMDM2OhreggsafD
I expect to detect the visted state when same domain regardless of the value of _gl params.

Answer (score -1):

> I expect to detect the visted state when same domain regardless of the value of _gl params.

You expect wrong.

Browsers track visited state based on the URL.

If you change the URL, then you change it to one that the browser hasn't visited before.

This also breaks caching.

---

For same site links, you could track which URLs have been visited (e.g. in a server-side session or with client-side JS in localStorage). You can normalise them to remove the `_gl` query paramater, then you can apply a `class` attribute and style based on that instead of the `:visited` state.

Caching will still be broken.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try the approach you provide.